# Save repeated computation in conditional expression in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

In the following code, I need to compute the maximum of the sum of one element from keyboards and one from drives, subject that the sum should be less or equal to `s`.

```
  (def s 10)
  (def keyboards '(3 1))
  (def drives '(5 2 8))

  (let [k (sort (fn [x y] (> x y)) keyboards) ; sort into decreasing
        d (sort (fn [x y] (> x y)) drives)    ; sort into decreasing
        ]
    (loop [k1 (first k) ks (rest k) d1 (first d) ds (rest d)]
      (cond
        (or (nil? k1) (nil? d1)) -1     ; when one of the list is empty
        (< (+ k1 d1) s) (+ k1 d1)       ; whether (+ k1 d1) can be saved to compute once?
        (and (empty? ks) (empty? ds)) -1
        (empty? ks) (if (< (+ k1 (first ds)) s) (+ k1 (first ds)) -1) ; whether (+ k1 (first ds)) can be saved once?
        (empty? ds) (if (< (+ d1 (first ks)) s) (+ d1 (first ks)) -1) ; whether (+ d1 (first ks)) can be saved once?
        :else (let [bs (take-while #(< % s) [ (+ k1 (first ds)) (+ (first ks) d1) ])]
                (if (empty? bs) (recur (first ks) (rest ks) (first ds) (rest ds))
                    (apply max bs))))))
```

As indicated in the comments, I wonder if there is any way to further optimize the repeated add operation in the conditional expressions. 
It may not be optimal to use let bindings to compute them all before the condition checkings, as only one of the condition would be true, thus the computations for the other conditions would be wasted.

I wonder if Clojure compiler would be smart enough to optimize the repeated computation for me, or there is a clever expression to make the operation to be performed only once in both the checking and return value?

Any suggestion to make the code more idiomatic would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but why are you worrying about the time it takes to calculate `(+ k1 d1)`?

Comment: I just want to learn to be as optimal as possible. Here the operation repeated is just 'add', very low cost. But the operation could be anything which may be much more expensive.

Comment: `(sort (fn [x y] (> x y)) keyboards)` is just `(sort > keyboards)`. `>` is a function like any other.

Comment: Don't use `-1` to indicate absence. Use `nil` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the structure of your current code, you can use Mark Engelberg's [better-cond](https://github.com/Engelberg/better-cond) library:

```
(require '[better-cond.core :as b])

(def s 10)
(def keyboards '(3 1))
(def drives '(5 2 8))

(let [k (sort (fn [x y] (> x y)) keyboards) ; sort into decreasing
      d (sort (fn [x y] (> x y)) drives)]   ; sort into decreasing
  (loop [k1 (first k) ks (rest k) d1 (first d) ds (rest d)]
    (b/cond
      (or (nil? k1) (nil? d1)) -1           ; when one of the list is empty
      :let [x (+ k1 d1)]
      (< x s) x
      (and (empty? ks) (empty? ds)) -1
      :let [y (+ k1 (first ds))]
      (empty? ks) (if (< y s) (dec y))
      :let [z (+ d1 (first ks))]
      (empty? ds) (if (< z s) (dec z))
      :else (let [bs (take-while #(< % s) [(+ k1 (first ds)) (+ (first ks) d1)])]
              (if (empty? bs) (recur (first ks) (rest ks) (first ds) (rest ds))
                (apply max bs))))))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I'm looking for! This might be another showcase of the magic of the macros.

Comment: Of course, I'm also open better idiomatic expression. Actually, my above implementation may have bug, sometimes it failed to find the maxim sum.

Comment: Please note that my above implementation is not correct. That of Josh below is the correct one. This serves well to introduce better-cond though.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds kind of like the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). There are more computationally efficient ways to compute it, but if you are dealing with two or three small lists which are less than a few hundred, and if it is not a critical piece of code that is running in a hot loop, consider the much simpler:

```
(let [upper-limit 10
      keyboards [3 1]
      drives [5 2 8]]

  (apply max
         (for [k keyboards
               d drives
               :let [sum (+ k d)]
               :when (<= sum upper-limit)]
           sum)))
```

You perform your (potentially expensive) computation only once (in the `:let` binding), which is what you really were asking for. This is `O(n^2)`, but if it meets the criteria above, it is a solution which can be understood easily to the reader; thus, it is maintainable. If it's critical that it be as efficient as possible, consider more algorithmically efficient solutions.

**Edited by Yu Shen:**

There is a slight problem when there no eligible sum. It may be improved as follows:

```
(let [upper-limit 10
      keyboards [3 1]
      drives [5 2 8]
      eligbles (for [k keyboards
                     d drives
                     :let [sum (+ k d)]
                     :when (<= sum upper-limit)]
                 sum)]
  (if (empty? eligbles)
    nil
    (apply max eligbles)))
```

Comment: thank for showing excellent readable expression. Yes, it's the intent.

Comment: I was just trying to implement a more algorithmically efficient solution.